# How to create a flexible MySQL search procedure?

Tags: mysql

Hello dearest community,

**EDITED**

This is my solution, based on [Devart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135566/devart) answer. I slightly modify the procedure parameter and also fix some `%` things..

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `cosmedicdb`.`proc_searchall` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `cosmedicdb`.`proc_searchall` (output TEXT, tbl varchar(50), kolom_kriteria VARCHAR(20),
                                               kolom_nilai VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN

  SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT ', output, ' FROM ',tbl,' WHERE ', kolom_kriteria, ' LIKE CONCAT(','\'%',kolom_nilai, '%\')');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I think one can enhance this to support search of numeric value field

**Original Question below**

First of all, I hope this  is not a repost question.
I want to create a flexible search procedure. That is, the column ad the value of the column to be search, can be supplied from the argument itself. Currently this is my search procedure looks like :

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `cosmedicdb`.`proc_searchtindakan` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `cosmedicdb`.`proc_searchtindakan` (kolom VARCHAR(20),
                                               kolomnilai VARCHAR(20))

BEGIN
 CASE kolom
 WHEN 'jenis'
         THEN
          SELECT jenis, harga
             FROM cosmedicdb.tb_mastertindakan
          where jenis like concat('%',kolomnilai,'%');
 END CASE;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

You can see that this procedure only work for certain column to be search. Is it possible (and safe) to create just one search procedure that allows me to search using any column  as the defining search criteria?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you not building the query string *before* sending the query to the database? Can you give examples of how you want to use it, and more of your requirements?

Comment: Hello @GustavBertram, yes indeed I am aware of that trick. Previously I work that way :building sql string and then sending it to be executed. But, currently I rewrote an existing vb.net+mysql application, that heavily rely on using MySQL Stored Procedure. And I am happy to know that the complexity can be separated into database server

Comment: Generally, stored procedures are a bad idea. They are *very* hard to debug, they are not portable, and in most cases, they do not give much of a performance boost. My suggestion is that you get rid of them everywhere they are not critical. For a query like the above, the better (more readable, better maintainable, more debuggable) way is to build the string.

Comment: I can understand your opinion. But, currently, I like the idea that all my data related code were moved to database. It's a data centric application anyway. And I can separate the work of creating the stored procedure as the work for the DB engineer him/herself. This way, it lift so much work from me as the programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html): build a query and execute it, e.g. -

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE proc_searchtindakan(IN kolom VARCHAR(20), IN kolomnilai VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
  SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT ', kolom, 'FROM cosmedicdb.tb_mastertindakan WHERE ', kolom, ' LIKE CONCAT(\'%\'', kolomnilai, '\'%\'');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

...in example I have removed 'harga' field from the list of fields; add it if you need.

Comment: Ow, I just know that we can build a query/prepare statement inside stored procedure. Let me test this. But, I already accept your answer as the default answer. Thanks!

Comment: I edit my question to show your answer, with modification of procedure parameter. But using this type of procedure, involve the application code to hardwired the table name. Somehow, I don't like it... :)